# change TextView height - iOS

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitextview

i have a xib file as tableview header cell which i want it to be self size. inside xib, i have a text view that i want to change its height on a button press. when btn is pressed, the textview's height should be the size to fit the text inside and when btn pressed again, it should resize to just two lines of text.

[image]

i used these lines of code in my btn action

```
    let contentSize = self.content.sizeThatFits(self.content.bounds.size)
    var frame = self.content.frame
    frame.size.height = contentSize.height
    self.content.frame = frame
```

it expands the textview but textview overlaps to elements below it. 
using two lines of code below for self sizing header makes every thing worse and it shows only two lines of textview and cm, like and others disappear.

```
    tableView.estimatedSectionHeaderHeight = 115.0
    tableView.sectionHeaderHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

how can i solve this?

Comment: Did you consider using AutoLayout?

Comment: @MCMatan i thought of it but i don't know how can i use auto layout to handle this?

Comment: AutoLayout is based on ratio to ether view elements, and this is exctly what you are trying to achieve

Comment: You can specify height constraint for textview and update it with the height you will get after calculating it from your above mentioned contentSize.height and that will do the job, I believe.

Comment: @ldindu actually textview expands but it overlaps with other elements

Comment: Your problem appeared to be not overlapping but underlapping as other view underneath textview underlap as you need to resize the tableview cell to account for updated textview height.

Comment: Right after self.content.frame = frame, you need to reload that particular table view cell to take account of updated textview height.

Comment: i used aspect ratio constraint and now textview is ok. but still self sizing won't work

Comment: I've never heard of term "aspect ratio constraint", what is that?

Comment: @ldindu no i mean i added constraint for aspect ratio of text view :D

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to do it using autolayout + UITableViewAutomaticDimension, check this out: 
http://candycode.io/self-sizing-uitextview-in-a-uitableview-using-auto-layout-like-reminders-app/